# Error creating environment in R to store a map from single character to int

Tags: r, dictionary, lookup

I am trying to implement a hash table in R, which according to [this](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/03/lookup-performance-in-r.html), should be done using environments.

Here is my code:

```
labeled.environment <- function(n) {
  e <- new.env(hash=TRUE,size=n)
  from <- "2345234523452345"
  to <- "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP"
  for (i in 1:16) {
    assign(x=chartr(from,to,i), value=i, envir=e)
  }
  e
}

e.20 <- labeled.environment(32)
get("B",envir=e.20)
```

The `get()` function returns: `Error in get("B", envir = e.20) : object 'B' not found`, which is probably caused by the duplicate items in the from string.

How do I correctly create a map from a single character to a numerical?

Comment: Look at `ls(e.20)`. Your use of `chartr` is the problem (you don't specify a one-to-one relationship).

Comment: The article (and code) you link to is an extremely clever way of setting up a benchmark.  I took me quite some time to decipher.  Sadly, it's not helpful to actually build the table itself.  I'll try to post an answer in few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An environment is for many practical purposes very similar to a list.  Thus your problem is how to add new elements to the environment.  Here are several ways of doing it:

Method 1. Use `list2env` to convert an existing list to an environment.

```
lookup <- list(x=1, y=2, z=3)
hash <- list2env(lookup, hash=TRUE)
```

Inspect some of the values:

```
hash$x
[1] 1

get("x", hash)
[1] 1

hash[["x"]]
[1] 1
```

Method 2: Add new elements using `$<-`:

```
hash$aa <- 99

ls.str(hash)

aa :  num 99
x :  num 1
y :  num 2
z :  num 3
```